# I am getting two error messages for my output

Tags: java, error-handling

this is my code:

```
public List<BookEntry> parseFileContent() {
        Objects.requireNonNull(fileContent, "ERROR: No content loaded before parsing.");
        return BookEntryCreator(fileContentListCreator(fileContent));
    }
```

I am expected to get this error:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: Console output not as expected in parseFileContent. 
Expected :ERROR: No content loaded before parsing.
```

However I am getting this one:

```
Actual   :ERROR: executing parseFileContent for console output check:java.lang.NullPointerException: ERROR: No content loaded before parsing.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you post you test code, pls?

Answer (score -1):

Your variable named "fileContent" is obviously null. Is it really neccessary which error you get and not how to fix them?